# Modify Vuex store by Cypress

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, cypress, vuex

I have to test a page via Cypress, the page using data from Vuex store to initialize itself.
The problem is that the store updates in the previous page, so I don't have the data set.
Example store:

```
user: {
someId: null // should be set before the page loading (or before reload),
anotherUserVariable: null
},
anotherVariable: null
```

I use Nuxt and in the console can invoke `window.$nuxt.$store` but not by Cypress.
Is it possible?